# Latent Semantic Indexing

Tags: svd, latent-semantic-indexing

I'm trying to find out how to carry out the multiplication of the matrices produced after SVD implementation in LSI. I need this for my research. I want to carry out document clustering.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, once you decompose the term-document matrix with the SVD to create [U, S, V], you need to multiple the singular values, S, with the left factor matrix, V'.  V' is your document-space matrix, which is scaled by the singular values.  The cosine similarity of the rows of the resulting matrix should give you document similarities.